# Different results in R console versus Jupyter

Tags: r, statistics, jupyter

I'm analyzing the agreement between two judges scoring the same item using Cohen's Kappa. To do it I'm using R and the Kappa.test() function from the fmsb package. When I run it in R console I don't get an error, but in Jupyter I do.

In R Console

```
     RD <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)
     BA <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)
     Kappa.test(RD, BA, conf.level=0.95)

$Result

    Estimate Cohen's kappa statistics and test the null hypothesis that the
    extent of agreement is same as random (kappa=0)

data:  RD and BA
Z = 1.7723, p-value = 0.03817
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.06683747 1.09982919
sample estimates:
[1] 0.5833333


$Judgement
[1] "Moderate agreement"
```

But in Jupyter I get

```
  Error in vapply(seq_along(mapped), function(i) {: values must be length 1,
     but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

Comment: Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?  In particular, can you post your Jupyter notebook somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: no error with your code, you still get the right output. `options(jupyter.display_mimetypes = NULL)` eliminates the message, but I'm not sure what that would be the best solution. or `options(jupyter.display_mimetypes = 'text/plain')`

Comment: With the tiny data set I used above I get the error. It does give me the right output after throwing that error but I was hoping to get an idea of why its happening and whether I need to double check my results with R console.